# how do I breakdown a string in multiple components

Tags: python, string

I have a string 'ABCAPITAL23JAN140CE'. This is the symbol for an option traded on stock exchange. ABCAPITAL part of the string is the company name. 23 is year 2023. JAN is for month. 140 is the strike price and CE is the type of the option.

All these components can vary for different options.

I need a function such that **pieces_of_string = splitstring('ABCAPITAL23JAN140CE')**

where
**pieces_of_string = ['ABCAPITAL', 23, 'JAN', 140, 'CE']** is returned

how do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might use re.findall with `[A-Z]+|\d+`

See the matches here on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AqkdfI/1)

```
import re
print(re.findall(r"[A-Z]+|\d+", "ABCAPITAL23JAN140CE"))

# Or converting to int
print([int(v) if v.isdigit() else v for v in re.findall(r"[A-Z]+|\d+", "ABCAPITAL23JAN140CE")])
```

Output

```
['ABCAPITAL', '23', 'JAN', '140', 'CE']
['ABCAPITAL', 23, 'JAN', 140, 'CE']
```

---

Another option with 4 capture groups matching the digits and the shorted part for the month like `JAN` `FEB` etc...

```
^(\S*?)(\d+)(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(\d+)(\S+)$
```

See the capture group matches on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aQwpsC/1)

```
import re
m = re.match(r"(\S*?)(\d+)(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(\d+)(\S+)$", "ABCAPITAL23JAN140CE")
if m:
    print(list(m.groups()))
```

Output

```
['ABCAPITAL', '23', '140', 'CE']
```

Comment: Doesn't it need to convert the numeric strings to `int` too?

Comment: @jvx8ss You could do that like `print([int(v) if v.isdigit() else v for v in re.findall(r"[A-Z]+|\d+", "ABCAPITAL23JAN140CE")])`

Answer (score 1):

```
def splitstring(s):
    l=[s[0]]
    for h in s[1:]:
       H=h + l[-1][0]
    
        if H.isdigit() or H.isalpha():
            l[-1]+=h
        else:
            l.append(h)
    return l
        
        

print(splitstring('ABCAPITAL23JAN140CE'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This method test if two adjacent characters are of the same type or not, if yes then concatenate the letters else split.

```
    st = 'ABCAPITAL23JAN140CE'
    l = []
    s = ""
    for i in range(0,len(st)-1):
        if (st[i].isnumeric() == st[i+1].isnumeric()) or (st[i].isalpha() == st[i+1].isalpha()):
            s = s + st[i]
        else:
            s = s + st[i]
            if s.isnumeric():
                l.append(int(s))
            else:
                l.append(s)
            s = ""
```

Output:

```
['ABCAPITAL', 23, 'JAN', 140]
```

Answer (score -1):

import re
print(re.findall(r"[A-Z]+|\d+", "ABCAPITAL23JAN140CE"))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).